# convolution:Unterstanding beginning of the proof

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, convolution

I got $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n}), g \in L^p(\mathbb{R^n}), p \in [1, \infty]$

Then $$ \int_{R^n} |f(x-y)|| g(y)| d^n y < \infty$$

Proof: Let $ \frac{1}{q} +\frac{1}{p} =1$

Then: $  $$ \int_{R^n} |f(x-y)|| g(y)| d^n y =  $$ \int_{R^n} |f(x-y)|^{\frac{1}{q}} \underbrace {| g(y)| |f(x-y)|^{\frac{1}{p}}}_{\in L^p  (1)}  d^n y$

Why does (1) hold?

Answer (score 2):

Since that $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $|f|=(|f|^{1/p})^p$ it's integrable, then $f^{1/p} \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and therefore $g(y)f(x-y)^{1/p} \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$,

Comment: Why is this  $g(y)f(x-y)^{1/p} \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \in L^p$?

Comment: Remember that $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and from what we saw $f^{1/p}\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, therefore $g\cdot f^{1/p}\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. See that $f(x-y)$ is a mere translation of $f$.

Comment: But the conclusion $ g \cdot f^{\frac{1}{p}} \in L^p $ is not the case in general?

Comment: @Steven33 if $g\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ then $g^p\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$: this implies *always* $g^pf\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$.

Comment: But why is that? Why do you need convolution then?

Comment: See,the convolution allow us to get a function in $L^p$ from a function in $L^1$ and a function in $L^p$ and the fact that $gf^{1/p}$ is in $L^p$ is a factor that makes this possible.

Comment: Nevertheless I don't get why $g^p f\in L^1 $ should hold?